# How to integrate libtomcrypt into u-boot?

Tags: cryptography, shared-libraries, u-boot

for a research project I need to incorporate different crypto functions (PRNG, SHA1, symmetric encryption/decryption) into the MLO part of u-boot.

My questions:

1.) Has someone achieved this before?

2.) Do you guys know it this is even possible regarding the limited size of the MLO and the size of libtomcrypt?

3.) Does someone know an elegant way of resolving missing *.h file-errors besides the straight forward way of copying them fomr /usr/include/ to {u-boot-src}/include/ ?

Thanks a lot.

`make` output:

> arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/libomap-common.o: In function `selectSecretBytes':
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:777: undefined reference to`register_prng'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:778: undefined reference to `find_prng'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:778: undefined reference to`rng_make_prng'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:779: undefined reference to `error_to_string'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:783: undefined reference to`fortuna_start'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:784: undefined reference to `error_to_string'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:788: undefined reference to`fortuna_add_entropy'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:789: undefined reference to `error_to_string'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:793: undefined reference to`fortuna_ready'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:794: undefined reference to `error_to_string'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:797: undefined reference to`fortuna_read'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:805: undefined reference to `fortuna_done'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:806: undefined reference to`error_to_string'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:816: undefined reference to `fortuna_desc'
>   arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/libomap-common.o: In function`createKey':
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:1088: undefined reference to `register_hash'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:1094: undefined reference to`find_hash'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:1104: undefined reference to `sha1_process'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:1114: undefined reference to`sha1_desc'
>   /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c:1114: undefined reference to `hash_descriptor'
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13036
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 2.20.51.20100809 assertion fail /scratch/janisjo/arm-linux-lite/obj/binutils-src-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elf32-arm.c:13291
>   /bin/sh: Zeile 1: 20550 Speicherzugriffsfehler  (Speicherabzug geschrieben) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld -pie -T u-boot.lds -Bstatic -Ttext 0x80E80000 $UNDEF_SYM arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.o --start-group api/libapi.o arch/arm/cpu/armv7/libarmv7.o arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/libomap-common.o arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap4/libomap4.o arch/arm/lib/libarm.o common/libcommon.o disk/libdisk.o drivers/bios_emulator/libatibiosemu.o drivers/block/libblock.o drivers/dma/libdma.o drivers/fpga/libfpga.o drivers/gpio/libgpio.o drivers/hwmon/libhwmon.o drivers/i2c/libi2c.o drivers/input/libinput.o drivers/misc/libmisc.o drivers/mmc/libmmc.o drivers/mtd/libmtd.o drivers/mtd/nand/libnand.o drivers/mtd/onenand/libonenand.o drivers/mtd/spi/libspi_flash.o drivers/mtd/ubi/libubi.o drivers/net/libnet.o drivers/net/phy/libphy.o drivers/pci/libpci.o drivers/pcmcia/libpcmcia.o drivers/power/libpower.o drivers/rtc/librtc.o drivers/serial/libserial.o drivers/spi/libspi.o drivers/twserial/libtws.o drivers/usb/eth/libusb_eth.o drivers/usb/gadget/libusb_gadget.o drivers/usb/host/libusb_host.o drivers/usb/musb/libusb_musb.o drivers/usb/phy/libusb_phy.o drivers/usb/ulpi/libusb_ulpi.o drivers/video/libvideo.o drivers/watchdog/libwatchdog.o fs/cramfs/libcramfs.o fs/ext2/libext2fs.o fs/fat/libfat.o fs/fdos/libfdos.o fs/jffs2/libjffs2.o fs/reiserfs/libreiserfs.o fs/ubifs/libubifs.o fs/yaffs2/libyaffs2.o lib/libfdt/libfdt.o lib/libgeneric.o lib/lzma/liblzma.o lib/lzo/liblzo.o lib/zlib/libz.o net/libnet.o post/libpost.o board/ti/panda/libpanda.o --end-group /home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524/arch/arm/lib/eabi_compat.o -L /opt/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.2/armv4t -lgcc -Map u-boot.map -o u-boot
>   make[1]: *** [u-boot] Fehler 139
>   make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/andre/tmp/working/chipsee/u-boot-ics-chipsee-panda-0524'
>   make: *** [omap4_panda] Fehler 2

Comment: My question is, why would you use libtomcrypt? Its pretty much abandoned, and there are superior libraries available including Botan, Cryptlib, Crypto++, and OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) Has someone achieved this before?

I have not.

> 2.) Do you guys know it this is even possible regarding the limited size of the MLO and the size of libtomcrypt?

`libtomcrypt` appears to be pretty much abandoned. There are probably better choices. Caveat emptor.

> 3.) Does someone know an elegant way of resolving missing *.h file-errors besides the straight forward way of copying them fomr /usr/include/ to {u-boot-src}/include/ ?

Use `--sysroot` to pass the root directory or `SYSROOT` of the arm headers and libraries. Under `SYSROOT`, there should be a `include/` and `lib`, and the compiler and linker will find required headers and libraries.

Or, pass the header path using `-I` and library path using `-L`.